# django-channels - group send does not call the function defined in "type"

Tags: django, django-channels

I have this Consumer:

```
class TableConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):            
    async def connect(self):
        self.table_name = f'table_test'
        self.channel_name = f'channel_test'

        await self.accept()
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.table_name, self.channel_name
        )
        await self.manage_new_game_video()
            
    async def manage_new_game_video(self):                
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.table_name, {"type": "chat_message", "message": "message"}
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        print("test")
        message = event["message"]

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": message}))
```

for some reason, the print statement is never executed and I don't understand why.

Why can that happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because I overrided self.channel_name.